ceph manager process hung due to high memory usages
I have observed that in one of my ceph manager nodes ceph-mgr process died due to high memory usages. The thread mentioned in the log in prometheus. So it is suspected that prometheus put some large memory allocation causing ceph-mgr service eventually went into out of Memory state. We have other manager node that are not observing the same issue. This is not frequent issue. Can I get some expert opinion where I can check why prometheus suddenly allocated large memory on that particular node?
tcmalloc: large alloc 1233903616 bytes == 0x5607ecec4000 @  0x7fa9345f3760 0x7fa934614a62 0x7fa93dbb65c8 0x7fa93dbe6365 0x5607122bac0b 0x5607122baef0 0x5607121e6e6d 0x7fa93dc63de7 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dc41998 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dc41998 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dbc1994 0x7fa93dc62e5f 0x7fa93dbcaa2b 0x7fa93dc66b9f 0x7fa93dbc2306 0x7fa93dc41b80 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dbc2ea2 0x7fa93dbc3c7e 0x7fa93dbd5f00 0x7fa93dbcaa2b 0x7fa93dc66b9f 0x7fa93dc41998 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8
 tcmalloc: large alloc 1542381568 bytes == 0x56078c6e4000 @  0x7fa9345f3760 0x7fa934614a62 0x7fa93dbb65c8 0x7fa93dbe6365 0x5607122bac0b 0x5607122baef0 0x5607121e6e6d 0x7fa93dc63de7 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dc41998 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dc41998 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dbc1994 0x7fa93dc62e5f 0x7fa93dbcaa2b 0x7fa93dc66b9f 0x7fa93dbc2306 0x7fa93dc41b80 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8 0x7fa93dbc2ea2 0x7fa93dbc3c7e 0x7fa93dbd5f00 0x7fa93dbcaa2b 0x7fa93dc66b9f 0x7fa93dc41998 0x7fa93dc64087 0x7fa93dc64cd8
 src/page_heap_allocator.h:74] FATAL ERROR: Out of memory trying to allocate internal tcmalloc data (bytes, object-size) 131072 48
*** Caught signal (Aborted) **
 in thread 7fa8ab726700 thread_name:prometheus
 2024-12-20T03:48:02.083+0800 7fa92c85c700 -1 received  signal: Hangup from Kernel ( Could be generated by pthread_kill(), raise(), abort(), alarm() ) UID: 0
Dec 20 18:59:34 storagessd02moc.osp.m1 systemd[1]: Stopping Ceph Manager...
 teardown: managing teardown after SIGTERM
Dec 20 18:59:34 storagessd02moc.osp.m1 ceph-mgr-storagessd02moc[3922]: teardown: Sending SIGTERM to PID 59
 2024-12-20T18:59:34.892+0800 7fa92c85c700 -1 Fail to open '/proc/718/cmdline' error = (2) No such file or directory
 teardown: Waiting PID 59 to terminate ..................................................<!>
teardown: TIMEOUT ! Let's consider it died and continue. Container will be reported in error.

